# Extract Information with brackets using python

Tags: python, regex

I got a badly managed log, and need to extract into a dictionary using Python.

```py
# Pattern: (keys are not kw1, kw2 ,etc... no pattern in key)
"para1=a, kw2=b, (b, b=b), bb, kw3=c, t4=..."

# where
# - para1=a
# - kw2=b, (b, b=b), bb
# - kw3=c
# - and so on

# extract into a dict:
out = {"para1": "a", "kw2": "b, (b, b=b), bb", "kw3": "c", "t4": ...}

# Notes several important features
'''
    1. all 'kw=value' are joined with certain spliter: ', '
    2. value and kw themselves may contain spliter. i.e. 'f(x, y)=3, f(x=3, y=2, z=1)=g(x=1, t=2)'
    3. all brackets must be in pair, (therefore we can identify spliters in kw or value).
    4. all message must be part of kw or value. 

'''
```

Q1: Is there a regex expression(`or some Python code`) that helps me get above key and value?
`There's no pattern in key, kwN is just a reference to key`

Q2`Update: Thanks to Laurent, I alr know why Q2 doesn't work`: Got unexpected result. ', (.*?)=' should give me the shortest matching between ',' and '=' right?

```py
msg = 'a, a, b=b, c=c'
re.findall(', (.*?)=', msg)
>>> ['a, b', 'c']
# I was expecting ['b','c']
# shouldn't ', (.*?)=' give me the shortest matching between ',' and '='? which is 'b' instead of 'a, b'
```

(New)Q3:  Since I'm working with huge loads of data, **working efficiency** is my first priority. I've worked out a python code which could achieve the goal, but it doesnt feel quick enough, **could you help me to make it better?**

```
def my_not_efficient_solution(msg):
    '''
    Notes:
    1. all 'kw=value' are joined with certain spliter: ', '
    2. value and kw themselves may contain spliter. i.e. 'f(x, y)=3, f(x=3, y=2, z=1)=g(x=1, t=2)'
    3. all brackets must be in pair, (therefore we can identify spliters in kw or value).
    4. all message must be part of kw or value. 
    Solution:
        1. split message with spliter -> get entries
        2. check each spliter bracekt and equal sign
        3. for each entry: append to last one or serve as part of next one or good with itself
    '''
    spliter=', '
    eq_sign=['=']
    first=False
    bracket_map={'(':1,")":-1,"[":1,"]":-1}
    pair_chk_func = lambda s: not sum([bracket_map.get(i,0) for i in s])
    eq_chk_func = lambda s: sum([i in s for i in eq_sign])
    assert pair_chk_func(msg), 'msg pair check fail.'
    res = msg.split(spliter)
    
    # step1: split entry
    entries=[]
    do_pre='' # last entry is not complete(lack bracket)
    do_first = '' # last entry is not complete(lack eq sign)
    while res.__len__()>0:
        if first and entries.__len__()==2:
            entries.pop(-1)
            break
        if do_first and entries._len__()==0:
            do=do_first+res.pop(0)
        else:
            do_first=''
            do=res.pop(0)
        eq_chk=eq_chk_func(do_pre+do)
        pair_chk=pair_chk_func(do_pre+do)
        # case1: not valid entry, no eq sign
        # case2: previous entry not complete
        # case3: current entry not valid(no eq sign, will drop) and pair incomplete(may be part of next entry)
        if not eq_chk or do_pre:
            if entries.__len__() > 0:
                entries[-1]+=spliter+do
                pair_chk=pair_chk_func(entries[-1])
                if pair_chk: do_pre=''
                else: do_pre=entries[-1]
            elif not pair_chk:
                do_first=do
        # case4: current entry good to go
        elif eq_chk and pair_chk:
            entries.append(do)
            do_pre=''
        # case5: current entry not complete(pair not complete)
        else:
            entries.append(do)
            do_pre=do
    
    # step2: split each into dict
    output={}
    split_mark = '|'.join(eq_sign)
    for entry in entries:
        splits=re.split(split_mark, entry)
        if splits.__len__()<2:
            raise ValueError('split fail for message')
        kw = splits.pop(0)
        while not pair_chk_func(kw):
            kw += '='+splits.pop(0)
        output[kw]='='.join(splits)
    return output

msg = 'B_=a, kw2=b, f(A=3, k=2)=g(t=3, v=5), mark[(blabla), f(xx tt)=33]'
my_not_efficient_solution(msg)
>>> {'B_': 'a',
 'kw2': 'b',
 'f(A=3, k=2)': 'g(t=3, v=5), mark[(blabla), f(xx tt)=33]'}
```

Comment: Do your keywords all start with `kw`?

Comment: @zooarcher could you try my answer and let me know if that helps you! :)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Thanks for the clarification, Yes, there's no pattern in KEYs, they dont start with kw.

Comment: @Himanshuman Thanks a lot bro! your result works great with KEY starting with kw, but mine doesnt start with kw, there's no pattern with KEYs, they may be: capital, non-capital, numbers, or even an expression including brackets(`a(x, y)=3`)... I've udpated the question~

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to Q1:**

Here is my suggestion:

```
import re
s = "kw1=a, kw2=b, (b, b=b), bb, kw3=c, kw4=..."
pattern = r'(?=(kw.)=(.*?)(?:, kw.=|$))'
result = dict(re.findall(pattern, s))
print(result) # {'kw1': 'a', 'kw2': 'b, (b, b=b), bb', 'kw3': 'c', 'kw4': '...'}
```

To explain the regex:

- the (?=...) is a lookahead assertion to let you find overlapping matches
- the ? in (.*?) makes the quantifier * (asterisk) non-greedy
- the ?: makes the group (?:, kw.=|$) non-capturing
- the |$ at the end allows to take account of the last value in your string

**Answer to Q2:**

No, this is wrong. The quantifier *? is non-greedy, so it finds the first match. Moreover there is no search for overlapping matches , which could be done with (?=...). So your observed result is the expected done.
I may suggest you this simple solution:

```
msg = 'a, a, b=b, c=c'
result = re.findall(', ([^,]*?)=', msg)
print(result) # ['b', 'c']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro! Especially for Q2, you saved my ass. But not all keys start with kw, my bad, I've udpated the question.... And solution doesnot work with below input, could you help me? input: `'kw1=a, kw2=b, kw3=g(t=3, v=5), mark[(blabla), f(xx, tt), kw5=33]'` >>> {'kw1': 'a',
 'kw2': 'b',
 'kw3': 'g(t=3, v=5), mark[(blabla), f(xx, tt)',
 'kw5': '33]'}

Answer (score 2):

**Q1: Is there a regex expression that helps me get above key and value?**

To get the key:value in a dictionary format you can use

Say your string is

```
"kw1=a, kw2=b, (b, b=b), bb, kw3=c, kw4=dd, kw10=jndn"
```

Using the following regex gives you key and values in a list

```
results = re.findall(r'(\bkw\d+)=(.*?)(?=,+\s*\bkw\d+=|$)', s)

[('kw1', 'a'), ('kw2', 'b, (b, b=b), bb'), ('kw3', 'c'), ('kw4', 'dd'), ('kw10', 'jndn')]
```

You can convert it to a dictionary as

```
dict(results)
```

Output :

```
{
    'kw1': 'a', 
    'kw2': 'b, (b, b=b), bb', 
    'kw3': 'c', 
    'kw4': 'dd', 
    'kw10': 'jndn'
}
```

Explanation :

- `\b` is used like a word boundary and will only match kw and not something like `XYZkw`
- `\kw\d+=` Match the word kw followed by `1+` digits and `=`
- `.*?` (Lazy Match) Match as least chars as possible
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert to the right

  - `\s*\bkw\d+=` Match optional whitespace chars, then pat, `1+` digits and `=`
  - `|` Or
  - `$` Assert the end of the string for the last part
- `)` Close the lookahead

Comment: Thanks a lot bro! not all keys start with ‘kw’, and kw themselves may contain brackets. And there's an exception here:
`msg = 'kw1=a, kw2=b, kw3=g(t=3, v=5), mark[(blabla), f(xx, tt), kw5=33]'`
`dict(re.findall(r'(\bkw\d+)=(.*?)(?=,+\s*\bkw\d+=|$)', msg))`
>>> `{'kw1': 'a',  'kw2': 'b',  'kw3': 'g(t=3, v=5), mark[(blabla), f(xx, tt)',  'kw5': '33]'}`